# Array initialization in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, initialization

I want to initialize an array with 10 values starting at X and incrementing by Y. I cannot directly use `range()` as it requires to give the maximum value, not the number of values.

I can do this in a loop, as follows:

```
a = []
v = X
for i in range(10):
    a.append(v)
    v = v + Y
```

But I'm certain there's a cute python one liner to do this ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 3
>>> [i*y + x for i in range(10)]
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> range(x, x+10*y, y)

[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39]
```

Comment: never try this with floats as x and y

Answer (score 2):

Just another way of doing it

```
Y=6
X=10
N=10
[y for x,y in zip(range(0,N),itertools.count(X,Y))]
[10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64]
```

And yet another way

```
map(lambda (x,y):y,zip(range(0,N),itertools.count(10,Y)))
[10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64]
```

And yet another way

```
import numpy
numpy.array(range(0,N))*Y+X
array([10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64])
```

And even this

```
C=itertools.count(10,Y)
[C.next() for i in xrange(10)]
[10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64]
```

Comment: `numpy.array(range…)`? Have a look at `numpy.arange`

Comment: The `np.arange(0,N) *Y+X ` is useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
[x+i*y for i in xrange(1,10)]
```

will do the job

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
Y = 6
a = [x + Y for x in range(10)]
```

Edit: Oh, I see I misunderstood the question. Carry on.